# cobol 85 , carriage return and line feed

Tags: carriage-return, linefeed, cobol85

I am coding in cobol85, I have an input file having 2 records as of now

```
""1";"S";"20140211095016";;;;;"KANATA";"ON";"K2V 1A5";"ZR1
;;;;;;;;;;"-503.15";;"1715.27";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"26696.33
";"78.22";"3275.95";;;;;"30050.50";;" 
""1";"S";"20140211088445";;;;;"MANATA";"ON";"K2V 1A5";"ZR1
;;;;;;;;;;"-503.15";;"1715.27";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"26696.33
";"78.22";"3275.95";;;;;"30350.50";;"
```

I am reading this input record and I want to put each record into different variables as of no into two different variables by inspecting carriage return or/and line feed but how can I do it I tried using "X'ODOA' but I couldn't separate it. Please help me how should I inspect and separate the records.

Comment: Thanks Michael for formatting for better understanding :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am asuming the first record finishes at `"30050.50";;"` and the second one starts at `""1";"S"`

If those are two separate records on a sequential file you don't need to inspect for CR or LF as each `READ` will read a new line.

Can you post the `SELECT` and `FD` of that file?

Comment: Yes Molusco your undersatnding for the records starting and ending is correct.
SELECT CPC-INVOICE-FILE  ASSIGN          TO TB9002D1
                         ACCESS MODE     IS SEQUENTIAL
                         ORGANIZATION    IS SEQUENTIAL
                         FILE STATUS     IS WS-CPC-FILE-STATS.

FD CPC-INVOICE-FILE
LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED.
  01  CPC-INVOICE-RECORD   PIC X(3530).

  And the input file is unstructured file.

Comment: as it is 01 CPC-INVOICE-RECORD PIC X(3530) I am getting complete input data in this variable and then I am using INSPECT command INSPECT CPC-INVOICE-RECORD TALLYING WS-TALL-CNT FOR ALL LINE-FEED still this inspect command is not checking for line feed or carriage return. Please help.

Comment: as of now my CPC-INVOICE-RECORD contains ""1";"S";"20140211095016";;;;;"KANATA";"ON";"K2V 1A5";"ZR1
;;;;;;;;;;"-503.15";;"1715.27";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"26696.33
";"78.22";"3275.95";;;;;"30050.50";;" "?13 ?10 " ""1";"S";"20140211088445";;;;;"MANATA";"ON";"K2V 1A5";"ZR1
;;;;;;;;;;"-503.15";;"1715.27";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"26696.33
";"78.22";"3275.95";;;;;"30350.50";;" "?13 ?10 "

Comment: And what was your approach to read the file? A `READ NEXT` loop? Can you post that too? I still don't think it is clear what are you trying to parse, as i told you, the `READ`s do it normally.